# Cannot call method toUpperCase of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
if (json.ScheduleCareProviderScheduledPatientsGetResult.Appointments[i].Patient.Firstname.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchBarValue.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
```

Why do i get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
json.ScheduleCareProviderScheduledPatientsGetResult.Appointments[i].Patient.Firstname
```

is undefined.

Comment: It could be that `searchBarValue` is undefined.

Comment: @Andy E I didn't bother to scroll that far :)

Answer (score 2):

Either `json.ScheduleCareProviderScheduledPatientsGetResult.Appointments[i].Patient.Firstname` or `searchBarValue` are undefined. Make sure they're not `null` before you call this line!